# Eval in Scheme accessing lexical variables

Tags: scheme, lisp, eval

```
(define x 44) (define y 25)
(let ((x 12) (y 23)) (if #f (eval x) (eval y)))
```

The above code returns 25, as eval uses global variables. How to create something similar to eval but looks for local variables when it sees variable references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what Scheme you're using, but in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) I get a different answer:

```
> (define x 44)
> (define y 25)
> (let ((x 12) (y 23)) (if #f (eval x) (eval y)))
23
```

This is the behavior I'd expect in any Scheme or Lisp. I think you meant to quote the `x` and `y` in `eval`:

```
> (let ((x 12) (y 23)) (if #f (eval 'x) (eval 'y)))
25
```

Now we get the result you were expecting. If you don't quote the argument to `eval`, then it gets evaluated and then passed in to `eval` as a value instead of a form. In the previous case, you end up with `(eval y)` --> `(eval 23)` --> 23. However, you can take advantage of this using [quasi-quoting](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/qq.html?q=quasi), selectively unquoting variables that you want evaluated in the current scope:

```
> (let ((x 12) (y 23)) (eval `(if #f ,x ,y)))
23
```

Comment: This is *not* the behaviour of any Scheme. Standard `eval` only has access to the global environment. Remember that Racket is not Scheme, that's the reason why they changed the name from PLT Scheme.

Comment: @asandroq What?! DaoWen's answer with quasiquoting actually applies to all Scheme implementations. It doesn't require `eval`ling through lexical variables; those actually get interpolated by the quasiquote.

Comment: @asandroq - Racket still [implements the R5RS and R6RS standards](http://racket-lang.org/new-name.html). From what I understand, the main reason for the name change was a branding issue (i.e. they wanted a name where their website could be the top hit on google).

Answer (score 2):

Most Scheme implementations do not support references to lexical variables in their `eval`. As a special case, [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) has [`local-eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Local-Evaluation.html) in its `(ice-9 local-eval)` module, which does support lexical variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other possible way to do it. I can't really do it for the moment but it can be done using an explicit environment.

If you look at the signature of `eval`, you'll see that it accepts a third parameter.

http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20eval#eval

```
[procedure] (eval EXP [ENVIRONMENT])
```

It might not be present on all scheme and even in chicken-scheme, this third parameter is almost useless at the moment.

What you could do is something like this.

```
(define x 25)
(define y 10)

(let* ((x 23)
       (y 21)
       (env (current-environment))

  (print (eval '(x y) env)))
```

This sounds good in words but the `current-environment` function is most likely to be the missing. I believe in gambit it is quite possible to do but even in chicken the environments module is deprecated and there is no alternative that I know of.